# Run a SQL statement in MySQL on each connection

Tags: mysql

I must be going nuts here, but I could swear I read about a configuration option in MySQL that will run the defined SQL statement on every successful connection to the database, with the cavet that it would not run for root or those with a certain privilege to prevent shutting the server down with a bad sql statement here.

Was I imagining things or do folks know of such a parameter?

I have dug though the MySQL documents and so far I'm not turning up with any success.

Note, this is NOT for the client supplied sql statements, but instead for a statement that the server itself runs regardless of who connects and for what task, and great for tracking who connects with what account if general_log was not enabled for some reason or special handling is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

The parameter is named [`init_connect`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_connect) and will run the defined sql for each connection, except for those with the super privilege. No result sets are produced by this though so selects are not recommended for this.

The big cavet I see here though is that access to the objects is based on the connecting user's permissions, which make sense.. though it does make an 'autorun' style stored procedure harder to implement as that procedure needs to be accessible to everyone, which could cause problems if it's written with the expectation to be executed only once per connection.

Comment: Interesting...  what is a good use case for this?

Comment: It's `init_command`, not `init_connect`.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_init-command

Comment: @dmikester1 You can use it for things like setting the timezone.

Comment: Oh, this is different from the mysql client `init_command` option.

Comment: "Interesting... what is a good use case for this?" @dmikester1 i had a wrong comment the last time.. imagine this it's a command line ... `--init-connect="SET NAMES utf8"` .. Still i would this from the application side tho.

Comment: Setting the names to utf is one case, an another might be to check and ensure that a user connects to the database only between certain hours for auditing purposes and security. ("why's chuck connecting to the DB at 3 in the morning on a saturday?")

Comment: My intended use is to take a long running database that has been up for about 5 years, and for much of that time, every developer could make accounts and databases with full root access. That has since been clamped down on, so now this is just part of the cleanup effort to figure out what accounts are used, and what we don't need.

Comment: You can also use [the General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) to audit user connections. It is *a general record of what mysqld is doing* (and can also be configured to log to a database table instead of a file).

Comment: Sadly we don't have the general log turned on due to security concerns with what data could get recorded in it, including encryption keys used inline in sql statements.

Comment: Look for "auditing" plugins.